# Is the term intellectual effrontery still in use? Does it sound clunky or stilted?

Tags: writing-style

I've encountered the term while reading an article on philosophy. I was wondering if it sounds clunky?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about writing but reading.

Comment: why where you wondering? it is philosophy ergo it is clunky :)

Comment: I believe it *could* be on topic, if a writer wanted to use it, but wasn't sure if they should. Unless edited, it should be closed.

Comment: It is fairly apparent that the OP is unsure how to reuse a new term that they have learned about.

Comment: It always sounded clunky and stilted.

Answer (score 1):

As with anything, it depends upon your intended audience. The term would be quite out-of-place in a street conversation, unless you were mocking a concept in the company of friends.

For people that are well-read, particularly those having read a fair amount of classical philosophy and participated in discussion, they would be more inclined to use and understand the term.

Now, to be cute, one can imagine toddlers playing around the sandbox, where one speaks of intellectual effrontery, and that could work from an humourous standpoint.